# Get the Average between two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a project on SQL Server and I need help trying to solve the average between two columns if that is possible. Here is my query I want sorted

[image: 2 Rows Needed to be Averaged]

```
SELECT 
    tblSchools.SchoolID, tblSchools.SchoolName, 
    tblWinds.MusicDescription, 
    AVG(tblWinds.Repertoire AND tblWinds.Performance) AS AvgScore
FROM
    tblSchools, tblWinds
WHERE 
    tblSchools.SchoolID = tblWinds.SchoolID 
    AND SchoolName = 'school'
GROUP BY 
    tblSchools.SchoolID, SchoolName, MusicDescription, tblWinds.Performance
ORDER BY 
    tblSchools.SchoolID ASC
```

I know the AVG function only needs one argument, but this is tough thinking. Is there a way to get the average of both columns?

Comment: Just call the `avg()` function twice. `select avg(tblWinds.Repertoire), avg(tblWinds.Performance) from ...`

Comment: The average of two rows? How do you know it is two rows? Are there exactly two MusicDescription per SchoolID? And why do you group by Performance? Isn't this one of the columns you want to get the average of? Please add sample data and the related expected result as formatted text to your request. ([Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551))

Comment: Do not use [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). Develop good habits.

Comment: Maybe just `(tblWinds.Repertoire + tblWinds.Performance) / 2` ? Just a wild guess...

Comment: Technically you mean "columns" rather than "rows". `(sum(repertoire) + sum(performance)) * 1.0 / (count(repertoire) + count(performance))` Or `(avg(repertoire) + avg(performance)) / 2` if you are certain the counts are the same.

Comment: Average of WHAT two rows?   What is the desired result here?

Comment: Yes, I too come to thinking this is a mistake and cube901 is not talking of two *rows*, but the average total of the values of two *columns*. shawnt00's solution is the correct one, working even for nullable columns and taking into consideration that SQL Server uses primary school math when it comes to integers. The Impaler's simpler solution is good for non-nullable decimal columns (there must be avg befor the opening paranthesis of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little algebra will be necessary for this one.

Either calculate the sums and counts manually:

```
(sum(repertoire) + sum(performance)) * 1.0 / (count(repertoire) + count(performance))
```

Or assuming that each average has the same denominator you can just average the averages:

```
(avg(repertoire) + avg(performance)) / 2
```